# Connect to PostgreSQL db with ado.net classes

Tags: .net, postgresql

so basically I am trying to connect to PostgreSQL based DB from .NET application with the connection string looking like this

```
Data Source=localhost;port=5432;Initial Catalog=testDB;User Id=postgres;Password=mypassword
```

and I am getting this error

```
ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
```

is there something wrong with my connection string ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is typically a problem of having the wrong driver installed, in particular confusion between the 32-bit and 64-bit drivers. Check to see which driver you have installed.

You may also try to set the Run64BitRuntime project setting to False if you have the 32-bit driver installed.

Comment: it actually was a problem with web config. I was not specifying the driver to use to connect to DB.